# How to extend a PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to cusmized my PythonOperator and place it under the $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins, like below:

```
class MyPythonOperator(PythonOperator):

    def my_callable(param1, param2, param3):
        # do something

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, task_id, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MyPythonOperator, self).__init__(
            task_id=task_id,  
            python_callable = self.my_callable,
            provide_context = True,
            *args, **kwargs)
```

Then I define a airflow dag code, it's very simple with only two tasks:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_workflow',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
)


task1 = MyPythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    params={'param1': 'param1_value',
            'param2': 'param2_value',
            'param3': 'param3_value'},
    dag=dag
)

task2 = MyPythonOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    params={'param1': 'param1_value',
            'param2': 'param2_value',
            'param2': 'param3_value'},
    dag=dag
)

task1 >> task2
```

but after I run the dag python code, get error message:

```
$ python example_airflow_code.py
[2019-05-15 19:51:10,338] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
usage: example_airflow_code.py [-h]
                               {list_tasks,backfill,test,run,pause,unpause,list_dag_runs}
                               ...
example_airflow_code.py: error: too few arguments
```

I tried some debug, and insert a breakpoint at this line:

`super(MyPythonOperator, self).__init__()`

I found before calling the super constructor, the values of self.dag and self.dag_id is abnormal, the value is:

```
str: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_6.4.4.201807281807/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 166, in _getPyDictionary
    attr = getattr(var, n)
  File "/Users/zhuangxy/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 2399, in dag_id
    return 'adhoc_' + self.owner
AttributeError: 'MyPythonOperator' object has no attribute 'owner'
```

Anyone knows what's the problem of this exmaple?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this one recently as well. It appears you're missing the `context` parameter on your custom PythonOperator.

Change your method definition so it looks like this:

```
def my_callable(param1, param2, param3, **context):
    # do something
```

The reason for the failure is the `provide_context=True` flag you've provided in the operator. For some reason the python callable is looking for it in your params.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend BaseOperator too:

```
import copy

from airflow.operators.python import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults


class CustomTask(BaseOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, prop1, dag, **kwargs):
        self.prop1 = prop1

        super().__init__(
            task_id=task_id,
            dag=dag,
            **kwargs
        )

    def execute(self, context) -> None:
        print(self.prop1)

        # use context here

        return request
```

And then:

```
task = CustomTask(
    task_id="TaskId",
    prop1="prop1",
    dag=dag
)
```